# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException only after multiple touch events

Tags: java, android, concurrentmodification

I get a `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` in my application, but only if I perform several touch events in rapid sucession, and seems to have more of an effect on slower devices (Samsung Galaxy S) as opposed to faster ones (Galaxy S3).

I have a queue where I store an array of int, to store the opacity and data for the points of the corresponding line. I remove the line from the queue when the opacity reaches 0, so it is no longer drawn.

Here's the stack trace:

```
01-10 14:06:27.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2081): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
01-10 14:06:27.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2081):     at java.util.LinkedList$LinkIterator.next(LinkedList.java:124)
01-10 14:06:27.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2081):     at com.android.mcameron.singletrack.Options$TestSurfaceView.drawLinesInvalid(Options.java:559)
01-10 14:06:27.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2081):     at com.android.mcameron.singletrack.Options$TestSurfaceView.run(Options.java:438)
01-10 14:06:27.847: E/AndroidRuntime(2081):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

These are the 2 functions that loop through the Queue and I perform my remove operation.

```
    private void drawLinesInvalid() {
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);

        for (Iterator<int[]> iterator = invalidLines.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            int[] invalidLine = iterator.next(); // Line 559 with the error
            float[] line = {invalidLine[1], invalidLine[2], invalidLine[3], invalidLine[4]};

            Xfermode originalXfermode = paint.getXfermode();
            paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
            mCanvas.drawLines(line, paint);
            paint.setXfermode(originalXfermode);
            paint.setAlpha(invalidLine[0]);
            mCanvas.drawLines(line, paint);
        }
    }

    private void decreaseLineOpacity() {
        for (Iterator<int[]> iterator = invalidLines.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            int[] line = iterator.next();
            if (line[0] <= 0) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }

        for (Iterator<int[]> iterator = invalidLines.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            int[] line = iterator.next();
            line[0] -= 10;
        }
    }
```

I've looked at a fair few other questions here, and most people seem to have problems with using Foreach loops, and performing the `remove()` operation on the queue rather then the iterator. Both of which I believe don't apply here. Also like said above I can get away with touching, so it's not an error that happens straight away. I can sometimes touch away 30-50 imes before it throws the exception.

Comment: Based on your code, it appears that `decreaseLineOpacity` and `drawLinesInvalid` are being called at the same time.  I would try a thread safe List like CopyOnWriteArrayList.

Comment: well I call them both in my thread one after the other, so quite possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Peter Lawrey, I used a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`

I changed my queue to this:

```
private CopyOnWriteArrayList<int[]> invalidLines = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<int[]>();
```

and then updated my decreaseLineOpacity to this:

```
private void decreaseLineOpacity() {
    int position = 0;
    for (Iterator<int[]> iterator = invalidLines.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        int[] line = iterator.next();
        if (line[0] <= 0) {
            invalidLines.remove(position);
        }
        position++;
    }

    for (Iterator<int[]> iterator = invalidLines.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        int[] line = iterator.next();
        line[0] -= 10;
        Log.d("Counting", "Opacity: "+ line[0]);
    }
}
```

I've been clicking away for a couple minutes and it hasn't thrown an exception, so seems good

Answer (score 0):

[`ListIterator`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ListIterator.html) used by `LinkedList` in android supports modification. So your problem must be related to multi-threading as @Peter Lawrey suggested. Try **synchronizing** both methods. If this affects performance you can try `CopyOnWriteArrayList` but this does not guarantee  you see the most updated changes while iterating in a thread because you are iterating through a copy of the list.